# Chrome extensions: Executing a script on every tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a plugin that affects every tab and window in the browser when the browser action is clicked.

This is the code I currently have:

```
function updateIcon() {
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:current});

  if (current == "icon-left.png") 
    { 
    current = "icon-right.png"; 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "cursor.js"});
    }
  else 
    { 
    current = "icon-left.png";
    chrome.tabs.reload(null);
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: `null` means: The current active browser. Loop through all active tabs, and use `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {...})`

Comment: Thanks @RobW, I tried something like this but no success `        chrome.tabs.query(null, function(tabz) {
                for (var i = 0; i < tabz.length; i++) {
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabz[i].id, {file: "cursor.js"});
                }
            }
        );`

Answer (score 5):

I solved in this way:

```
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
            for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {file: "cursor.js"});
            }
        }
    );
```